# Can't open SD card files, card locked by Bitlocker in Windows

Tags: password, encryption, ssd

When I open the SD card it shows different files related to the password created by Bitlocker in Windows. How can I enter the password, unlock the card, and access the files?

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure the SD card is not physically locked with a lock switch, as shown below.

[image: picture of SD card with lock switch]

The most reliable way is to put it back on the Windows PC with Bitlocker which locked it, and unlock it there.

The Linux alternative is [Dislocker](https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker), installed with

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install dislocker
```

Dislocker needs two directories so make them with

```
sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlocker && sudo mkdir -p /media/bitlockermount
```

Run gparted and confirm the encrypted card is **/dev/mmcblk0p1** (and if not, substitute its name for **/dev/mmcblk0p1** below)

Then open the encrypted card and mount the unencrypted volume in /media/bitlockermount with

```
sudo dislocker /dev/mmcblk0p1 -u<password> -- /media/bitlocker    

sudo mount -o loop /media/bitlocker/dislocker-file /media/bitlockermount
```

You can use the recovery password instead of the user password by replacing the first dislocker line above with

```
sudo dislocker /dev/mmcblk0p1 -p<password> -- /media/bitlocker
```

Lastly, open **/media/bitlockermount** with your GUI file manager, and there are your files.

Comment: I used windows BitLocker.

Answer (score 0):

I am only *guessing*, but it is most likely your SD was encrypted using BitLocker on Windows. If so, you need another computed with Windows AND the same password used as encryption key.

Be it BitLocker or any other encryption software, it is **mandatory** that you have the password. If you don't have it, you will never be able to retrieve the original information. Sorry, no donut for you this time.

Comment: Yes, it's BitLocker and I have the password. So, I can only unlock it with a windows pc?

Comment: Yes, only with a Windows PC. Unfortunately. You may try Dislocker as suggested by K7AAY, but I've never seen it in action.